# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error Apache poi in Android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I am getting below error when trying to run my Android project with Apache poi. Actually I am getting the error when I am adding a specific poi library(poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar). If I remove this library the project compiles, but with this following stacktrace occurs.

```
trouble writing output: Too many methods: 66024; max is 65536. By package:
    13 java.lang
     1 java.lang.reflect
     5 java.util
     1 javax.xml.namespace
    66 org.apache.xmlbeans
    19 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values
     1 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xmlschema
  2500 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart
  1430 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.impl
  8767 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main
  5258 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.impl
    86 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture
    33 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.impl
   745 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing
   417 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl
   230 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing
   164 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.impl
   298 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties
   256 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl
   617 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes
   596 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes.impl
   285 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties
   196 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl
    23 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math
    24 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships
     2 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships.impl
  2076 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main
  1224 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.impl
     1 org.openxmlformats.schemas.schemaLibrary.x2006.main
  7271 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main
  4556 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl
 11448 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main
  9217 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl
     4 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707
  1170 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel
  1223 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.impl
   285 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice
   124 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.impl
     2 schemasMicrosoftComOfficePowerpoint
     3 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord
  2858 schemasMicrosoftComVml
  2529 schemasMicrosoftComVml.impl
[2013-04-27 10:20:02 - TestProject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2
```

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: stop with the single tag edits, they're all completely unnecessary

Comment: @OGHaza - Okey. I thought is might be useful for people who add tags for finding question. Like me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dex` format has a limit of 65536 methods per file. You will probably have to split. Here is a discussion thread on the same with Google Engineers.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/sR6I2ldCxwU